# Orbit calculation for normaliser when orbits under centraliser action is known

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions

I was solving a problem and in the middle, I came across this. I will be really grateful for any help here. In the following, we fix the integer $s\ge 2$.

> Let $U\le \operatorname{GL}(2^s,\mathbb Z)$ be a finite $2$-group. Let $N=N_{\operatorname{GL}(2^s,\mathbb Z)}(U)$ and $C=C_{\operatorname{GL}(2^s,\mathbb Z)}(U)$ be the normaliser and centraliser respectively. Suppose $N$ is acting on a set $S$, in particular $S\le \mathbb Z^{2^s}$ and action of $N$ is defined via "right multiplication".

My question is:

> If we know the orbits in $S$ under the action $C$, then is there any result (or any method) which describes the orbits under $N$? Does the famous $N/C$ Theorem help in any way?

Any reference or hint will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A start is provided by noting that $N$ permutes the $C$-orbits in a length preserving manner.

Comment: Thanks. It will be very helpful if you kindly give some more hints and any reference please. Thanks again.

Comment: As well as the $C$-orbits, you need to understand how these are permuted by the group $N/C$. This would be explained by understanding the treatment of finite permutation groups in a group theory or algebra text.